# Need various ways to come up with this output

Tags: java

I am supposed to come up with this output.

[image]

But I am getting this instead..

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Sample{

     private String name;
     private Hashtable customers = new Hashtable();
     private Hashtable movies  = new Hashtable();

     public Sample(String aName){
         name = aName;
     }

     public String getName(){
         return name;

     }

     public void setName(String aName){
         name = aName;
 }
  public void addCustomer (Customer customer) {
    customers.put(customer.getName(), customer);
     }

     public Customer getCustomer (String customerName) {
        return (Customer)customers.get(customerName);
   }

     public void addMovie (Movie movie) {
        movies.put(movie.getName(), movie);
     }

     public Movie getMovie (String movieName) {
        return (Movie)movies.get(movieName);
   }

     public void error (String message) {
     System.out.println ("ERROR: " + message);
   }

     public Enumeration getMovies() {
     return movies.elements();
   }
     public Enumeration getCustomers() {
     return customers.elements();
   }
      public void showAll() {
     System.out.println ("name: "+ this.getName());
     Enumeration kk = this.getCustomers();
     while (kk.hasMoreElements()) {
       Customer one = (Customer) kk.nextElement();


       System.out.println (one.show());
     }
     Enumeration ff = this.getMovies();
     while (ff.hasMoreElements()) {
       Movie one = (Movie) ff.nextElement();
       System.out.println (one.show());
     }
   } 
public void test()  {
         Customer k1 =  new Customer ("Jonah")   ; this.addCustomer (k1);
         Customer k2 =  new Customer ("Hellen") ; this.addCustomer (k2);
         Customer k3 =  new Customer ("Agnes")  ; this.addCustomer (k3) ;
         Movie f1 = new Movie ("StarWars"); this.addMovie (f1) ;
         Movie f2 = new Movie ("Shrek"); this.addMovie (f2) ;
         System.out.println("-**-**- test part 1 -**-**-") ;
         this.showAll();

         System.out.println("-**-**- test part 2 -**-**-") ;
         System.out.println("---" + k1.getName() + " rents " + f1.getName());
         this.showAll();
         k1.doRent(f1);
```

MY CUSTOMER CLASS:

```
package eric;

public class Customer {

 String name;
    public Customer(String nameCus){
        name = nameCus;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String show(){

        return name;

    }


    public void doRent(Movie f1) {

     System.out.println(" -"+ " RentData" + "[" + getName() +"," + f1.getName() + "]" );

        }

        }
```

MY MOVIE CLASS:

```
public class Movie {

    String name;
    int x = 0;



    public Movie(String nameMov){
        name = nameMov;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }  


        public String show(){
            return name+"\n"+" - average: "+x +" days\n"+" - number of rentings: "+x ;


        }

}
```

My problem is that i cannot find a way to fix `-RentData [Jonah,StarWars]` under the name Jonah... Instead it comes at the end of output.. I need some one to help me figure how am ganna do that.. thanks

Comment: You've got a lot of bad formatting going on, maybe try and clean this up a little then repost? I tried editing it some to make it clearer for now...

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `k1.doRent(f1)` before `this.showAll()` so naturally you will get the "RentData..." line printed before the names are printed. The way your code is now is not conducive to what you're trying to do at all. Your `Customer` class should have a member list called `rentedMovies` that is populated every time you call `doRent(...)` on a `Customer` object. Then, `Customer.show()` should print the name of the customer, followed by your "RentData..." stuff that comes from `rentedMovies`.